# Push object onto appointments array

Tags: arrays, ruby, push

I have to put the information from appt2, and push it into my appointments array.

What I have so far:

```
appointments = []
appt2 = MonthlyAppointment.new("Doctor", "Cold", 2, 30, 15)
appointments.push(appt2)
```

What can I fix?

Comment: Well done I'd say. So what? :)

Comment: Is the code correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems. But we should see even `MonthlyAppointment` class.

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: You need to give us more info and try to ask better question. I have to agree with @Ursus that "So what?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the intermediate variable if you're just making one thing:

```
appointments = [
  MonthlyAppointment.new(...)
]
```

You could use the `<<` alias for `push`:

```
appointments << appt2
```

What you have there is fairly typical Ruby code.